# issue with java ant build(not setting the classpath correctly)

Tags: java, ant

Whats wrong with this build file. It is basically including two jar files AbsoluteLayout.jar and swing-layout-1.0.3.jar

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <project>
  <property name="srcDir" location="src"/>
  <property name="buildDir" location="build"/>
  <property name="distDir" location="dist"/>
  <property name="library" value="lib/"/>


  <path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${library}">
      <!--<include name="**/*.jar"/>-->
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>

  <property name="myclasspath" refid="classpath"/>
    <!-- Emit the property to the ant console -->
      <echo message="Classpath = ${myclasspath}"/>

  <target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${buildDir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${distDir}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="${srcDir}" destdir="${buildDir}" classpathref="classpath"/>
  </target>

  <target name="dist" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${distDir}/pro.jar" basedir="${buildDir}">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Main.Class"/>
      </manifest>
    </jar>
    <!--<jar destfile="${distDir}/package-src.jar" basedir="${srcDir}"/>-->

  </target>

  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${buildDir}"/>
    <delete dir="${distDir}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

It says BUILD SUCCESSFUL.When I run ant file in terminal. But when 
I run the jar file it is giving following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/layout/GroupLayout$Group
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout$Group
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

Why it not including the two files in classpath ?

Comment: I don't see where you've told it to. You've put "built-by" and "main-class" in the manifest, but what about "class-path"?

Answer (score 1):

> But when I run the jar file it is giving following error:
>
> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
> ```

This is a runtime error. The jdesktop jar is not available in the classpath of the jar file while running.

try

```
java -cp .;path_jdesktop.jar; yourclass.jar
```

You can add the [classpath in the manifest file](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) of the jar file also:

```
Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name
```

So something like:

```
 <manifest>
    <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Main.Class"/>
    <attribute name="Class-Path" value="lib/jdesktop.jar"/>
  </manifest>
```

And while running the jar file make sure there is a `lib` directory and `jdesktop.jar` in that `lib` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a path structure to build your classpath. For example you could read all jar files from your lib directory:

```
<target name="init-classpath" depends="retrieve">
    <path id="lib.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
</target>
```

But classpath takes list of paths separated by spaces, so you need to flatten your path structure:

```
<pathconvert property="mf.classpath" pathsep=" ">
    <path refid="lib.classpath" />
    <flattenmapper />
</pathconvert>
```

Finally put your mf.classpath in Class-Path property:

```
<jar destfile="${jars}/${result.name}.${result.ext}">
    <manifest>
        ...
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${mf.classpath}" />
    </manifest>
    ...
</jar>
```

In this case you need to deploy your library jars in the same directory as your output jar.